# Selenium - what is the difference between LoadableComponent and SlowLoadableComponent

Tags: selenium, selenium-webdriver, automated-tests, selenium-chromedriver, refactoring

What is the specific difference between LoadableComponent and SlowLoadableComponent in Selenium support classes?

How and when to use one over the other?

Comment: A `LoadableComponent` will fail immediately if an element is not found in `isLoaded()` while `SlowLoadableComponent` will retry until timeout when `.get()` is called. The `SlowLoadableComponent` is mainly used for implicit waiting for elements added dynamically to the page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My understanding is you would use both for components or elements that take some time to load, and the verification of what it means to be loaded is complex enough to be abstracted to a separate method `isLoaded`. The difference is that for `LoadableComponent` the call to `get()` must give you a fully loaded component, or throw an error, while `SlowLoadableComponent` may be returned unloaded.

That said, `LoadableComponent` would be used for elements you are only interested in once they are fully loaded and ready to use. You don't mind waiting for them to fully load and have no case to interact with them in their intermediate state. And if they fail to load - that means test over. Main use case I'd imagine is simply hiding the logic behind page loading and waiting for it.

`SlowLoadableComponent` on the other hand can be returned from its `get` method before it loads fully, giving you control over things like putting assertions on its load time in test (instead of hardcoding them in the component) or having a chance to interact with other elements that may affect the component loading. I can imagine a testcase relying on `SlowLoadableComponent` never being fully loaded under certain circumstances (e.g. checkbox not ticked) which is NOT a cause for execution failure.

Answer (score 1):

The `SlowLoadableComponent` is a subclass of the `LoadableComponent` but **does not have to finish loading** when load() returns. After a call to load(), the isLoaded() method will be failing until the component fully loads.

You use `SlowLoadableComponent`, if you do not need to call `get()` method immediately (because it needs it to be fully loaded) and you want to continue to perform some other actions first. But as soon as you need to perform `get()`, you should apply `isLoaded()` to be sure you can proceed with your code.

Overall, `SlowLoadableComponent` can speed up execution of your code, if you need `get()` at later stage or might not need it at all.